# Loading x amount of records into a repeater

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, webforms, repeater

I have been given responsibility of an older ASP.NET site which contains a page which lists users. The problem is, there are upwards of 40,000 records and the page currently works by running a stored procedure to get every one of them. This data is then bound to a repeater. As you can imagine, this process is painfully slow.

Is there any way for me to simply load x amount of records into the repeater, yet still enable pagination? For example I would like to:

1) Load the first 15 records by passing appropriate parameters into the sproc

2) Still allow the user to navigate to the next page and update the sproc to get records 16-30

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and/or literature you can direct me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered to add custom pagination to your repeater control?http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345

I think you'll need to refactor your store procedure to support custom pagination as well (I case you haven't), you will need to handle the pagination logic yourself but it's quite easy to implement.

Comment: This appears to be what I'm looking for - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to load the records partially: page by page. Or you can preload some pages and cache them and then update your cache again